# Get value of this field into this variable

Tags: php, variables, session-cookies

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['regduser']); 
$mypassword = $_POST['regdpass'];
$mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword.$salt);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE regduser = '$myusername' AND regdpass = '$mypassword')";
$studentID = $_POST['stuID'];
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count=1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("regduser");
session_register("regdpass"); 
header("location:/student.php?stuID=$studentID");
}
else {
echo "$mypassword<br />";
echo "$badpasses<br>";
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Specifically on this line:

```
header("location:/student.php?stuID=$studentID");
```

Why isn't `$studentID` getting any value in the above code? The field name `stuID` is getting selected in the `SELECT` statement above it. How do I get this value to be the value of `$studentID` ?

Thanks. Sorry if its a little newbish, I'm new to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are currently doing is gettin the 'stuID' from $_POST (from user input/http request), just like you are getting the user/pass

you want to fetch the result (that contains the 'stuID') from the SQL

after $result=mysql_query($sql);

change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE regduser = '$myusername' AND regdpass = '$mypassword')";
$studentID = $_POST['stuID'];
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count=1){
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE regduser = '$myusername' AND regdpass = '$mypassword')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($user){   // login success
    $studentID = $user['stuID'];
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking the value of `$count` with `==`, you are assigning the value:

```
// This...
if($count=1){

// Should be...
if($count == 1){
```

Note also that the `header("Location")` call, to conform to the HTTP spec, should be a full URL:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/student.php?stuID=$studentID");
// Also, you must call exit() right after to prevent further execution of your script
exit();
```

Finally, you called `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `regduser`, but you must also call it on `$myusername` and `$mypassword`.

Answer (score 0):

You're never using the result of the database query! In particular, the line

```
$studentID = $_POST['stuID'];
```

is *not* getting the value from the database, but rather from the HTTP POST parameters. You have to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or something like that at some point:

```
$qures = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$studentID = $qures["stuID"];
```

(This is just conceptually. You should do the check for the number of results first and make sure that there *is* a result.)